# HTML accept attribute multiple image types

Tags: html

In my code I have got this input type file:

```
<input type="file" id="chatsf" accept="image/png,image/jpg">
```

What I want is this input to only accept PNG and JPG files, but with my code it only accepts PNG files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the correct string for `.jpg` files is `image/jpeg`:

`<input type="file" id="chatsf" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" />`

Answer (score 3):

Note that the [IANA Media Type](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#image) for JPG images is `jpeg`, so simply use:

```
 <input type="file" id="chatsf" accept="image/png,image/jpeg">
```

You could also use `image/*` to allow all images.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!